# add suggestions in adaptive cards

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I need to add suggestions in adaptive card to be rendered on MS Teams.I have the list of suggestions from backend which i need to display as action buttons and when user clicks on any of the suggestion button the text needs to be displayed back as user message.
I tried using for each loop to iterate through list of suggestions but only the last suggestion comes up as an action button.How to display all suggestions as action buttons and display the text selected as user message?

```
 "messages": [
        {
            "suggestion": [
                "Good",
                "Great",
                " what can genie do for me."
            ],
            "user_msg": "Hello, How are you?"
        }
    ]
```

c#:
 var list = row["suggestion"];

```
    foreach (var li in list)
                {
                    card.Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>()
                    {

                        new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                        {
                            Title = li.ToString(),
                            DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"book-user-meeting\" }",

                        }
                    };
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you're completely recreating the card.Actions property every single time inside the "for" loop.  Your code should look something like this:

```
foreach (var li in list)
                {
                    card.Actions.Add(
                        new AdaptiveSubmitAction
                        {
                            Title = li.ToString(),
                            DataJson = "{ \"Type\": \"book-user-meeting\" }",

                        }
                    );
                }
```